# Is it so easy to show a locally bounded function with holomorphic cross sections is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and suppose every coordinate cross section of $f$ is holomorphic (I hope that's not too colloquial).

I've heard it's a somewhat deep theorem that this is enough to imply f is continuous, and therefore holomorphic as a function of n variables.  However when one uses Cauchy's formula (in one variable) to get a power series expansion of $f$ in a neighborhood of a point, one seems only to use that $f$ is locally bounded (so one can bound the values of f on the distinguished boundary of a polydisc). Is that correct? I.e. does {locally bounded} + {holomorphic cross sections} so easily imply holomorphic or have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if $f$ is locally bounded and separately holomorphic, it's not hard to see that $f$ is in fact continuous and jointly analytic. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185438) for more details.

As zwh pointed out, $f$ being separately holomorphic is enough, but this is a lot more difficult to prove.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to assume $f$ is holomorphic in each variable separately. This is a nice result of Hartogs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs'_theorem

Comment: Right I read that. I was just asking if it follows immediately from Cauchy's integral formula in one variable if you additionally assume locally bounded

Comment: Basically I want to be sure I understand where continuity is used in the preliminary proof that holomorphic functions of several variables have normally convergent power series in a neighborhood of a point